# Saving an IDataset that can be imported later to the database

Tags: java, dbunit

Is there a way that one could save a dbunit dataset(IDataset) as some other file than xml or csv?

I would like to import the created dataset later back to the database.

I'm creating a partial dataset containing of tables:

```
QueryDataSet partialDataSet = new QueryDataSet(dataBaseConnection)
partialDataSet.addTable("tableName");
// save as a file
// import the file later
```

I tried saving the dataset as .xml, but the order of rows is not correct if there is a dependency to another table.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `DatabaseSequenceFilter` and `FilteredDataSet` as described in DBUnit FAQ.

For you this might be:

```
QueryDataSet partialDataSet = new QueryDataSet(dataBaseConnection)
partialDataSet.addTable("tableName");
IDatabaseConnection connection = getConnection();
//Following filter will sort tables in correct order
ITableFilter filter = new DatabaseSequenceFilter(conn);
IDataSet dataset = new FilteredDataSet(filter, partialDataSet);
FlatXmlDataSet.write(dataset, new File("data-in-correct-order.xml"));
```

This xml later can be imported correctly into the DB.

http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#tableseq